# Time Machine progress from the command line

Tags: time-machine, command-line

The *Time Machine* control panel gives information on in-progress backups. For example

[image]

Is there a way to get the information from the command line?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

While the backup is running, detailed information gan be gained by

```
tmutil status
```

which should return something like this:

```
Backup session status:
{
    BackupPhase = Copying;
    ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
    DateOfStateChange = "2014-12-18 14:14:21 +0000";
    DestinationID = "B4AF88-5AD5-49BE-B254-650B44E20499";
    DestinationMountPoint = "/Volumes/TimeMachine";
    Percent = "0.852581430477103";
    Progress =     {
        TimeRemaining = 0;
        "_raw_totalBytes" = 38596759;
        bytes = 36563200;
        files = 480;
        totalBytes = 42456434;
        totalFiles = 480;
    };
    Running = 1;
    Stopping = 0;
    "_raw_Percent" = "0.9473127005301144";
}
```

If you only care for the percentage, try the following (looks ugly, works only if there is a percentage to display):

```
tmutil status | awk '/_raw_Percent/ {print $3}' | grep -o '[0-9].[0-9]\+\(e-[0-9]\+\)\?' | awk '{print $1*100}'
```

**Updated 10 years later:**

To better parse tmutil's plist output using builtin methods, you need to remove the initial line with `tail` and then convert it to JSON via `plutil`:

```
tmutil status | tail -n +2 | plutil -convert json -o - -- - | jq
```

Note that the pipe into `jq` is given here only for nicer formatting. To directly access individual values, instead use e.g.:  `| jq '.["BackupPhase"]'`

Comment: I couldn't find this in the manpage. Where did you glean this verb for `tmutil`?

Comment: @jsejcksn To be honest, I don't remember where I found out about `status`, running `tmutil help status` now returns `*** status is a private verb. ***`; why this is the case and especially *if* this was the case two years ago, I don't know :D

Comment: What is the format of the data from `tmutil`?  It's not quite JSON.  Is it some kind of C object dump?

Comment: @LS this is formatted as a [NeXTSTEP-style property list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list)

Comment: JSON files are somewhat brittle.  Using a tool like `jq` which understands JSON to extract information might be a better approach.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sure, but that's not valid json ;-)

Comment: @asmus. Yes. I need glasses.

Comment: for reading as json you can do a `tmutil status | jc 1: --plist -p` ( see https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc )

Comment: @muescha Thanks for bringing this old post back onto my radar, I've now updated my answer to also include a conversion to JSON using only builtin tools.

Answer (score 10):

To get only the percentage value:

```bsh
tmutil status | LC_NUMERIC="C" awk -F'"' '/_raw_Percent/ {print $4 * 100}'
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this with the `watch` command like this `watch -n 2 "tmutil status | LC_NUMERIC='C' awk -F'\"' '/_raw_Percent/ {print \$4 * 100}'"` to get an update e.g., every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make a simple script from the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/162515/98602).

```bsh
tmstatus () {
  eval $(tmutil status | grep -E '[^}];$' | perl -p -e 's/^\s+[\"]*//g;' -e 's/[\"]*\s+\=\s+/=/g') || (echo "Something get wrong..." && return 1)

  if [[ $Running -eq 1 ]]
  then
    export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
    [[ $BackupPhase == "Copying" ]] && Percent=$(printf '%0.2f%%' `bc <<< $Percent*100`) && echo "${DateOfStateChange} ${BackupPhase} backup to ${DestinationMountPoint}: ${totalFiles} files - ${Percent} (~$((${TimeRemaining:-0}/60)) min." || echo "${DateOfStateChange} ${BackupPhase} (Destination ${DestinationID})."
  else
    echo "TimeMachine backup is not running."
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit more complicated but also more practical for processing, the following command will write the progress status into a plist file and convert it into json:

```
tmutil status | grep -v 'Backup session status' > a.plist; plutil -convert json a.plist
```

Json can be parsed more easily to extract various information.

Answer (score 0):

I used @Atika's very helpful script but sometimes got errors like

```
bash: 26520.80484282512/60: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".80484282512/60")
```

So I made a slight tweak to pass that division operation to `bc` and now it works reliably (caveat: for me!):

Before:

```
(~$((${TimeRemaining:-0}/60)) min."
```

After:

```
(~$(bc <<< ${TimeRemaining:-0}/60) min.)
```

Updated Script:

```
tmstatus () {
  eval $(tmutil status | grep -E '[^}];$' | perl -p -e 's/^\s+[\"]*//g;' -e 's/[\"]*\s+\=\s+/=/g') || (echo "Something get wrong..." && return 1)

if [[ $Running -eq 1 ]]
then
  export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
  [[ $BackupPhase == "Copying" ]] && Percent=$(printf '%0.2f%%' $(bc <<< $Percent*100)) && echo "${DateOfStateChange} ${BackupPhase} backup to ${DestinationMountPoint}: ${totalFiles} files - ${Percent} (~$(bc <<< ${TimeRemaining:-0}/60) min.)" || echo "${DateOfStateChange} ${BackupPhase} (Destination ${DestinationID})."
else
  echo "TimeMachine backup is not running."
fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a script for this that can be executed from Terminal.

https://github.com/fedekrum/Mac-Time-Machine-status

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if we're root and re-run if not.
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Script not running as root, trying to elevate to root..."
    sudo bash "$0" "$@"
    exit $?
fi
clear

# Get the PID of the process "/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd"
PID=$(ps -ef | awk '$8=="'/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd'" {print $2}')

# If the process is not found, it alerts the user and quits
if [ -z "$PID" ]; then
    echo "The process '/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd' is not running"
    exit 1
fi
clear

# Loop to continuously check the status
while true; do
    echo -e "\033[H"

    # Check if the output of "tmutil status" contains "ThinningPreBackup"
    if tmutil status | grep -q "ThinningPreBackup"; then
        # If it does, run "lsof -p $PID" and show the last line as the status
        echo
        printf "$(lsof -p $PID | tail -n 1 | awk -F'/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}' '{print substr($2, 2)}')\n"
    else
        # If it doesn't, show the result of "tmutil status"
        echo
        printf "$(tmutil status)\n"
    fi

    # Get the width of the terminal
width=$(tput cols)

# Generate a line filled with spaces
line=$(printf '%*s' $width)

# Do it for three lines
for i in {1..3}; do
    # Print a carriage return and the line of spaces, effectively overwriting the current line with spaces
    echo -en "\r$line\r"

    # Move to the next line
    echo
done

    # Wait for 10 seconds before the next round
    for i in {10..1}; do
      echo -e "\033[H"
      echo "$i "
      sleep 1
    done
done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Link only answers are not appreciated, especially if your GitHub account goes, then your answer is worthless. At least provide a copy of the script here (like other answers do), and explain it's workings.