# Is there a way to see progress on Time Machine Restore, seeming stuck on "preparing to restore" animation?

Tags: backup, time-machine, ssd, restore

Short story:

Macbook pro Retina 13" early 2015 with 128GB SSD /8GB RAM
free space left <5GB

- I bought a new 512GB SSD
- I did Time Machine backup on a encrypted
  external usb HDD (~64GB)
- I Replaced the SSD
- Macbook turned on pressing Cmd+opt+R
- Erased the new SSD (MACOS Extended Journaled filesystem)
- Then selected to restore system from a TimeMachine disk
- Unlocked the encrypted Time Machine volume for restoring
- Selected the new clean SSD as target

Finally started the Restoring: seeing a "nice" animation with no progress. Both the Macbook and the disk seem to be quiet. I left it running for a couple of hours no signals of moving  forward

NOTES:

- I opened the log window available during  the restore no logs there about the Restoring process
- My Time machine backup is not big size: around 64GB
- I stopped the procedure two times (after waiting 2h each) and when interrupted looking at the SSD from disk utility seems like nothing relevant happened/was written inside
- I tried then a new install of MacOS Monterey (there I have an estimation!   2 hours to complete install) then will try migration assistant.... hopefully this could be a time-boxed way around(?)

**Question is:**

How can I possibly understand if the Restore procedure is stuck and I'm wasting my time or if it's really working and it really needs longer time to be restored on a new SSD?

Any experience on this ?
How long Recover from  TimeMachine did take for you?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/162515/88313) help?

Comment: That aswer says: "While the backup is running", I'm restoring instead and there's no visible  chance to have a terminal available....

Comment: Got it, sorry about that.

Comment: I finally was able to restore the TM backup on a clean install Monterey. using migration assistant. ~1h to install Monterey + ~1h for data migration  Still wonder if there’s a chance to restore it directly or may not be the right way

Comment: Monterey should insist on being installed on APFS, not HFS+ - wonder if something choked & didn't tell you.

Comment: Dont get the point of your comment @Tetsujin, why are u assuming I had HFS+?

Comment: It's stated in your question - "Erased the new SSD (MACOS Extended Journaled filesystem)"

Comment: Ok I realised now that MACOS Extended Journaled uses HFS Plus. But the thing is... Having it formatted like that I was able to then install Monterey (and now in fact as you say it is APFS). Restoring directly on the formatted ssd HFS+ the TimeMachine backup (which was Catalina 10.15) instead didn't start...

Comment: Catalina is also APFS. I think the insistence started with perhaps Monterey, prior to that I recall it was optional [or you could force it].